# How are 2d Array and pointers related?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Why is these two are same things I saw one answer to this similar question but couldn't really understand.

Why `*(a+i)` and `a+i` doing the same work.

```
int a[1][2] = {1,2};
printf("%p or %p\n",*(a+0),a+0);
```

Comment: `*(a+0)` means `a[0]`,  and `a+0` means `&(a[0])`.  `a[0]` is an array (the first row of `a`), so this is the same question as asking why an array's address is equal to its value

Answer (score 1):

Array subscript brackets "[]" are *defined* in terms of pointer operations. a[i] is defined as *(a+i), assuming that a is of type array and i is an integer type. The name of an array by itself is evaluated as a pointer to its first element; integer addition to a pointer adds the integer times the sizeof the element to the pointer. (a+i) and *(a+1) are not the same - (a+i) is the address of an element in an array and *(a+i) is that element.

Thus a[0] becomes *(a+0), or *a, the first element of the array. A[1] becomes *(a+1), or *(a + (sizeof (*a) * 1), or *(address of the second element of the array), or just the second element of the array, as one would expect.

Comment: yeah but still why *(a+0) is not printing the value of a[0][0] it is printing its ADDRESS.

Comment: @user8740705: Because `*(a + 0)` is equivalent to `a[0]`, and the *type* of `a[0]` is `int [2]`.  Since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to a pointer to the first element, so `a[0]` is equivalent to `&a[0][0]`.

Comment: @JohnBode: The type of a[0] actually changes depending on whether it's an lvalue or rvalue in the expression. As an lvalue, it's int[2], but as an rvalue, it's int *. Try putting in a line "a[0] = a[1]" and see what happens. You'd think they would have to have the same type, but they don't. Yes, this is very confusing, and I didn't want to complicate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So given a declaration like

```
int a[100];
```

any time `a` appears in an expression where it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the compiler will treat it as a pointer expression equivalent to `&a[0]` (type `int *`).

Now, what happens if `a` is the operand of unary `&`?

The address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array, which should be clear from the diagram below:

```
   +------+
a: | a[0] |
   +------+
   | a[1] |
   +------+
     ...
   +------+
   | a[99]|
   +------+
```

The *type* of the expression `&a` is `int (*)[100]` (pointer to 100-element array of `int`), but the *value* of the expression is the same as `a` and `&a[0]` (address of the first element).

Summarizing that in a table:

```
int a[100];

Expression         Type          "Decays" to          
----------         ----          -----------           
         a         int [100]     int *                 
        *a         int           n/a                   
        &a         int (*)[100]  n/a                   
      a[i]         int           n/a                   
     &a[i]         int *         n/a
```

Again, the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array, so `&a`, `a`, and `&a[0]` will all yield the same address value (modulo any type conversions).

Adding 1 to a pointer yields the address of the next object of the pointed to type.  IOW, if `p` points to a 4-byte `int` object, the result of `p + 1` will be the address of the next 4-byte `int`.  If `p` points to a 100-element *array* of 4-byte `int`s, then `p + 1` yields the address of the next 100-element array of `int`.

The subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given the address `a`, find the address of the `i`'th object following `a` and dereference the result.

This means that the value of `*a` is the same as `a[0]` - `*a == *(a + 0) == a[0]`.

How does this apply to a 2D array, as in your example?

Given the declaration

```
int a[1][2];
```

the *expression* `a` "decays" from type "1-element array of 2-element array of `int`" (`int [1][2]`) to "pointer to 2-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[2]`).  The value of the expression `a` is the address of the first element, but the first element has an array type itself.  Thus, that value "decays" to a pointer to the first element of the subarray.

Here's a handy table to summarize:

```
int a[1][2];

Expression         Type            "Decays" to          
----------         ----            -----------          
         a         int [1][2]      int (*)[2]           
        *a         int [2]         int *                
        &a         int (*)[1][2]   n/a 
      a[0]         int [2]         int *
     *a[0]         int             n/a
     &a[0]         int (*)[2]      n/a
   a[0][0]         int             n/a
```

Again, `&a`, `a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` will all yield the same value, since the address of `a[0][0]` is the same as the address of `a[0]` which is the same as the address of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

C's doesn't really treat multidimensional arrays differently from single-dimensional ones.
Arrays in C are just array of arrays

```
char a[2][3][4][5];
```

is an [array 2 of array 3 of array 4 of array 5 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+a%5B2%5D%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%5B5%5D%3B).

Dereferencing/subscripting works the same for any  "Array A of T":

- decay A to the address of the first element (or do nothing if you're defering/subscripting a pointer)
- add to that the index scaled by `sizeof(T)`

With dereferencing/subscripting in C, when you speak of one, you speak of the other, because `A[Index]` or `Index[A]` is defined to be the same as `*(A+Index)` or `*(Index+A)`.

[6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Since in `char a[2][3][4][5];` `a` is an *array 2 of ( array 3 of array 4 of array 5 of char)*, `a[1]` would give you `((char*)&a) + 1 * sizeof(char[3][4][5])` and the result would have type `char[3][4][5]`.

Now here's where arrays are special — arrays aren't first-class objects in C. You can't have an r-value of an array type. When you attempt to obtain one, e.g., by passing the array to a function or an operator, the array immediately decays to a pointer to its first element so the `char[3][4][5]`  type of `a[1]` immediately changes to `char(*)[4][5]`.

[6.5.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p3)

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object. If E is an n-dimensional array (n >= 2) with dimensions i x j x . . . x k, then E (used as other than an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an (n - 1)-dimensional array with dimensions j x . . . x k. If the unary * operator is applied to this pointer explicitly, or implicitly as a result of subscripting, the result is the referenced (n - 1)-dimensional array, which itself is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).

This continues recursively until you've chomped off all of the dimensions (from right to left) and are left with a real type that doesn't decay. Effectively the decay of the intermediary arrays means that intermediary derefs/subscripts don't really fetch anything — they're simply additions to a base address.

Some examples with `char a[2][3][4][5];`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char a[2][3][4][5];
#define ASSERT_TP(Expr,Tp) _Generic(Expr,Tp: (char*)(Expr))
int main()
{
    printf("%zd\n", ASSERT_TP(a,char(*)[3][4][5]) 
                   - (char*)a); //0
    printf("%zd\n", ASSERT_TP(a[1],char(*)[4][5]) 
                   - (char*)a); //60 == 1 * (3*4*5)
    printf("%zd\n", ASSERT_TP(a[1][1],char(*)[5]) 
                   - (char*)a); //80 == 1 * (3*4*5) + 1 * (4*5)
}
```

Applied to your example:

```
int a[1][2] = {1,2}; // a decays to ptr to 1st element, 
                     //i.e. to `int (*a)[2]`
printf("%p or %p\n",
        *(a+0),  // == a[0]; ((char*)&a) + 0*sizeof(int[2]); 
                 // type is int[2], which decays to int*
        a+0);    // == a (after decay); (char*)&a + 0*sizeof(int[2]); 
                 //type is still `int(*)[2]` (because no derefing)
```

Because the deref in `*(a+0)` didn't hit the real type yet, there was no fetch, just an addition to a base pointer
with type adjustement. Since the addition added 0, the value didn't change it remained the same as that of `a` decayed to a pointer to its first element (== `a+0`) or even `&a` (which would have the same numerical address but its type would be `int (*)[1][2]`).

Answer (score 0):

An array can *decay* to  pointer to its first element. In your example plain `a` will decay to `&a[0]`. And for *any* array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`.

Also, if you lay out your array how it would look like in memory, it would be

```
+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] |
+---------+---------+
```

Now armed with this information, we can start transforming the expressions in your `printf` call.

Lets start with `*(a + 0)`:

1. Because the equivalence, `*(a + 0)` becomes `a[0]`.
2. Because `a[0]` is an array, it will decay to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `&a[0][0]`.

So the first argument is equal to `&a[0][0]`, i.e. a pointer to `a[0][0]`.

Then lets take `a + 0`.

1. The expression `a + 0` is equal to `&*(a + 0)`.
2. Because the array/pointer equivalence `&*(a + 0)` becomes `&a[0]`.

`&a[0]` is a pointer to the first element of `a`, which happens to begin at the same position in memory as `a[0][0]`.

This of course means that the pointer `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` both are pointing to the same locations, and the output would be equal. ***However*** the types of those two pointers are very different:

- The type of `&a[0][0]` is a pointer to an `int`, i.e. `int *`
- The type of `&a[0]` is a pointer to an array of two `int` elements, i.e. `int (*)[2]`