# How to use pointer arithmetic with dereferencing and addition?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, math

I just took an exam for my Computer Science class. On the exam, there was an 2-D int array and we were asked to compute the values. I thought I understood pointer arithmetic, but I got half of them wrong, so I was hoping someone here could explain it better.

I've watched a few Youtube videos and looked at multiple different lecture slides/notes and am still having trouble grasping the concept when it is a 2-D array, I understand a one dimensional one.

int a[2][3] = {{30,40,50} , {60,70,80}};
show the results of the following:
1. a =
2. a[0] =
3. a + 1 =
4. a[0][0] + 1 =
5. *a[0] + 1 =
6. *(a[0] + 1) =
We are to assume that the addresses start at 0x100.

I gave the following answers:
1. a = 0x100
2. a[0] = 0x100.
3. a + 1 = 0x112.
4. a[0][0] + 1 = 0x112.
5. *a[0] + 1 = 11.
6. *(a[0]+1) = 0x104.
........................................................................
I got 3 half credit for 3, 4 wrong, and 6 wrong. 
If I could change my answer now, I have no idea why 3 is wrong, no idea why 4 is wrong, and I believe 6 would be 40.

Comment: A recent qeustion you might find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656197/how-are-2d-array-and-pointers-related/54657911

Comment: What size are your ints?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the size. The ints are 4 bytes, even though on the exam he didn't bother to even specify that.

Comment: 0x112 is 18 bytes beyond 0x100, because 12 in hexadecimal is 18 in decimal. Since `int` is four bytes, a+1 should be 4•3 = 12 bytes beyond 0x100, which is 0x10c.

Comment: You should nor get any credit for 3

Comment: @EricPostpischil 4*3*2

Comment: @P__J__: No. 4*3*2 has no bearing on `a+1`. Each element of `a` is one array of three `int`, which is 12 bytes total. So `a+1` is 12 bytes beyond `a`.

Comment: 5. should be 31. Did you get credit for that, or was it marked wrong? Perhaps the 11 above is a typo?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I got full credit for the answer of 11. How is it not 11? De-referencing a[0] yields 10. 10+1 is 11.

Comment: @TristinB: How could dereferencing `a[0]` yield 10? There is no 10 in the array. It contains 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, and 80.

Comment: @EricPostpischil hahahaha you are VERY CORRECT. If it started at 10, then it would be 10 + 1 but it is 30. He must have overlooked that, I got lucky on that then. I see it now.

Comment: `a =`  would result in a compilation error, it's not really clear what is meant by "show the results of the following: a =" etc.

Comment: @M.M the exact directions say "write the numerical value of the expressions" and just has a box next to a, not a =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“3. a+1 = 0x112” is wrong:

- `a` is at 0x100. The elements of `a` are arrays of three `int`. `int` is four bytes, so three `int` is 12 bytes, so the elements of `a` are 12 bytes. So `a+1`, which is one element beyond `a`, is 0x100 + 12 = 0x10c.

“4. a[0][0] + 1 = 0x112” is wrong:

- `a[0][0]` is 30. 30+1 is 31.

“6. *(a[0] + 1) = 0x104” is wrong:

- `a[0]` is the first element of `a`, so it is array of three `int` containing 30, 40, and 50. As an array in a general expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so it points to 30. Adding 1 yields a pointer to the next element, so `a[0]+1` is a pointer to to 40. Then dereferencing that with `*` produces 40.

Comment: Yes, I see what I did now. I did not think of them as Hexadecimals, rather Decimals. So, when I said 0x112, I have the concept correct. I wanted to move 12 bytes up the array index, BUT it is Hex so 12 bytes of increase actually yields 0x10c not 0x112. And I see my mistake with the a[0][0] +1, as this is accessing the actual number inside of the array at the index of [0][0], and then adding one to it. And finally, on question 6(just to clarify) a[0]+1 is the address 0x10c, and then it is being de-referenced so it is the value 40?

Comment: @TristinB: `a[0]+1` points to 0x104, not 0x10c. Dereferencing the pointer to 0x104 produces 40.

Comment: @TristinB: In `a[0]+1`, `a[0]` is an array, so it is converted to a pointer to its first element, `&a[0][0]`. So `a[0]+1` is `&a[0][0]+1`. The left side of the `+` is a pointer to an `int`, and the right side is 1, so the sum is a pointer to 1 int further, which is `&a[0][1]`. (Not `a[0][0+1]`, which is the element, but `&a[0][1]`, which is a pointer to the element.) Then `*(a[0]+1)` is `*(&a[0][1])`, which is `a[0][1]`, which is 40.